# AWS Cloud 9 no installing to use CS50 IDE

Tags: amazon-web-services, ide, cs50, cloud9

This is the message I see when I try to install AWS Cloud9 installer:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download AWS Cloud9! Just go to ide.cs50.io.